# PIG replace for multiple columns

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a total of about 150 columns and want to search for \t and replace it with spaces

```
A = LOAD 'db.table' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
B = GROUP A ALL;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE REPLACE(B, '\\t', ' ');
STORE C INTO 'location';
```

This output is producing ALL the only word as output.

Is there a better way to replace all columns at once??

Thank you 
Nivi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a Python UDF.  Say you had some data like this with tabs in it:

**Data**:

```
hi    there    friend,whats    up,nothing    much
yo    yo    yo,green    eggs, ham
```

You could write this in Python

**UDF**:

```
@outputSchema("datums:{(no_tabs:chararray)}")
def remove_tabs(columns):
    try:
        out = [tuple(map(lambda s: s.replace("\t", " "), x)) for x in columns]
        return out
    except:
        return [(None)]
```

and then in Pig

**Query**:

```
REGISTER 'remove_tabs.py' USING jython AS udf;
data = LOAD 'toy_data' USING PigStorage(',') AS (col0:chararray,
       , col1:chararray, col2:chararray);
grpd = GROUP data all;
A = FOREACH grpd GENERATE FLATTEN(udf.remove_tabs(data));
DUMP A;
```

**Output**:

```
(hi there friend,whats up,nothing much)
(yo yo yo,green eggs,ham)
```

Ovbiously you have more than three columns, but since you are grouping by all, the script should generalize to any number of columns.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I still have question on what you wrote.
1) if the delimiter changes example: pigstorage('\0001') can handle the udf ?
2) why do we need to FLATTEN in the code , we have group all, this should consider it as one single line and do a simple regex replace ?

Comment: Okay, what is your question?

Comment: Also, the code is getting stuck in 1 reducer if use the above, i still dont find a reason why ..

Comment: You can change the delimiter in the UDF to whatever you want.  I just used `\t` because that's what you said you wanted.  You *could* use the `REPLACE()` function built into Pig but you'd have to write it 150 times.

Comment: Sorry, I would like to rephrase the questions: 
1) What if the delimiter between the fields/columns are different, i believe that pigstorage should handle this right ? Alos, I understand UDF is replacing the values within these fields. 
2) why do we need to use FLATTEN udf after the data is removed with tabs.
3) why does the code run on one reducer, should this task be done on the mapper side ?